# Loop through multidimensional array database response to extract data PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to loop though the array below and display an HTML table with the data from "type" in one column and the data from "description" in the other.

How do I do this in PHP?

Below is a print_r of my array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [type] => Printing and Scanning Facilities
            [has_amenity] => 1
            [description] => Please keep your self to less than 50 pages per day!
            [owner_desk_id] => 3
            [created_at] => 2013-10-07 05:14:06
            [updated_at] => 2013-10-07 05:14:06
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [type] => Climate Control
            [has_amenity] => 1
            [description] => We have heating for winter but no air conditioning. BYO fan.
            [owner_desk_id] => 3
            [created_at] => 2013-10-07 16:30:56
            [updated_at] => 2013-10-07 16:30:56
        )

)
```

Comment: Please at least post a formatted version of `print_r` output. `<pre>` tag is your friend -- `echo '<pre>', print_r($yourArray),'</pre>';`

Comment: @Amal, think that should be `print_r($yourArray, true)`?

Comment: Or just view the source of the page, producing an HTML-render-free version

Comment: @halfer: [Nope.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Kgm2LA)

Comment: @Amal, ah, we're both half right! Thanks for live sample. I thought `print_r` would output before the `<pre>`, which is what happens if you concatenate `'<pre>' . print_r($yourArray) . '</pre>'`. It seems the comma form of echo evaluates the clauses separately. That said, `print_r` without the `true` outputs a stray "1", which I think is the boolean result of the call, and thus is presumably not output you want.

Comment: @halfer: You're right, it's better to use the version with `true`, but the other one works, too. And I don't think the extra `1` matters much, in *this* case.

Comment: I've fixed the formatting now! I also used printr($array, true) after seeing what was mentioned regarding the additional 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$i = 0;
while(isset(yourArray[$i])) {
 foreach(yourArray[$i] as $key => $value) {
  if(($key == "value") || ($key == "description")) 
   $resultArray[$i][$key] = $value; //Store in a resultArray or you can even print HTML depending on what you want
 } 
 $i++;
}
```

Above is the kind of looping you'll need to do to extract specific data from your array.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nicer way (imo) :

```
$rowCount = count($yourArray);
for($i=0; $i < $rowCount; $i++) {
    $resultArray[$i]["value"] = $yourArray[$i]["value"];
    $resultArray[$i]["description"] = $yourArray[$i]["description"];
}
```

or a 2nd way if you don't care about indexes :

```
foreach ($yourArray as $rowNumber => $row) {
    $resultArray[]["value"] = $row["value"];
    $resultArray[]["description"] = $row["description"];
}
```